# Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler position change with defined height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please suggest a better title to this question if you can think of one.

I've run into this problem with two separate projects now. In bootstrap 4, the position of the navbar-toggler button is moving position when clicked if the nav element has a defined height.

I've created a fiddle to display the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/3xLwf19L/1/

Try clicking the icon whilst .navbar-custom has a height, and try again when no height is defined.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what, if there is one, the solution is?

HTML:

```
<nav id="site-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom fixed-top smooth-slow">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler .navbar-inverse hamburger-icon" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-custom {
    /*height: 80px;*/
    background-color: #FDC529;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
    border-width: 0 0 1px; 
}
```

Comment: i used your code its  not shoeing up the navbar infact i have write it up an span ytag and then on click nothing is coming up

Comment: please share the full code

Comment: @nikhilsugandh The full code contains too much now to be worth sharing, the fiddle I linked in the post contains all the relevent code and replicates the issue.

Comment: i face the same problem. Did you have solve this ? Thank you

Comment: @JoffreyHernandez Unfortunately not, the current work around I'm using is that the height can be controlled by the height of other elements inside it. You can add top and bottom padding to the li elements for example and it works successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Well I was facing exact issue and tried some experiments and fixed it, just define this in custom css file to override the padding issue:

```
.navbar {padding: 1.5rem 1rem;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to this:

```
.navbar {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

Comment: It appears to be the padding which is causing the repositioning, however the nav bar still doesn't move downwards with the links when clicked if a height is defined.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-custom {
    height: 80px;
   background-color: #FDC529;
   font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
   border-width: 0 0 1px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<nav id="site-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom fixed-top smooth-slow">
  <div class="container">
   <button class="navbar-toggler .navbar-inverse hamburger-icon" type="button" 
      data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
   </div>
    
      <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
 
 </nav>
```

Your toggle menu is nested inside the navbar with the button. When this is clicked it un-collapsed adding height pushing the button outside the navbar over the top of the screen.

To resolve this, move the closing div of your container to un-nest the menu.

```
<nav id="site-navbar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-custom fixed-top smooth-slow">
<div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler .navbar-inverse hamburger-icon" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div> ---------> closing tag for the contanier
    <div id="navbarSupportedContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link smooth-slow" href="">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The rest will just have to be styling.(proper padding.. etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried what you suggested but the same errors still remain.

Comment: I tried with your js fiddle and it was working. Let me insert a runnable in there.

Comment: BTW, I replaced the bootstrap cdn as your current one runs to scripting error.

Comment: @Xander same result if you remove the class container.